# A cancel .ICS works in Outlook Windows App but not Outlook 365. Why?

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I'm a novice programmer trying to send colleagues staffing assignments, from an outdated DB, as .ICS files. I've gotten the following things to work swimmingly in Outlook Windows:

1. Add a single event with an .ICS attachment
2. Add multiple events with an .ICS attachment
3. Cancel a single event with an .ICS attachment

So what's the problem? Many of my colleagues use Macs, and I can't get the cancel-event to work with Outlook for Mac OR Outlook 365. On the latter, I'm getting the dreaded "Couldn't import calendar. Try again later."

I'll paste in a sample below, but I'm confident I have the formatting right (and have checked it with a validator); UID is constant; Sequence is incrementing; Last-Modified is updating. I've tried both "Method: Request" and "Method: Cancel" with no change.

I've also read through countless posts and understand this is a long-standing issue.

Right now my best guess is that this isn't an issue with the ICS itself, but with the MIME Content-Type in the Email header. I've confirmed that this is NOT being set as text/calendar, but I don't know of any way to change this.

Hope that's enough info. If anyone has any insight on how I can make this work, would be grateful.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID://Workplace//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:F499BCFD-16DB-2A40-B1E1-F8D64F6A9B36
SEQUENCE:5
DTSTAMP:20210630T165316Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Live Programs:
 MAILTO:XXX@xxx.org
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;
 PARTSTAT=TENTATIVE;CN=Matt P
 :MAILTO:ZZZ@zzz.org
DTSTART:20220703T154500Z
DTEND:20220703T164500Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20210713T134505Z
LOCATION:Theater One
SUMMARY:12:00pm Show (Presenter)
STATUS:CANCELLED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: You suggest that the issue has to do with not setting `Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8` right? If this is the case you should add some details about the language/library you're using to build the emails.

My personal experience with this is: emulate Google calendar's notification emails as closely as you can, because that's what other calendars are testing against. Good luck though; the Outlook web client fails in some pretty inscrutable ways.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether it will work or not, but can you try once with METHOD:REPLY.